# Copy the content of one file to another excluding a few files

Tags: powershell

I made 3 folders in `C:\` drive — `new folder1`, `new folder2`, and `new folder3`.
`new folder1` contains five `.txt` files, `new folder2` contains the same five files plus a few more.

Now I want to compare both folders `1` and `2`, and copy **only the common files from** `new folder1` to `new folder3`. (It's like taking a backup of common files from `new folder1` and `new folder2`.)

I want to exclude copying all the uncommon files.
The code I wrote is:

```
cls
$folder1 = dir C:\new folder1
$folder2 = dir C:\new folder2
$difference = Compare-Object $new folder1 $new folder2
write-host "`n Missing files are " $difference
foreach($i in $folder1)
{
copy-item C:\new folder1 -Destination C:\new folder3 -Exclude $difference -Recurse
}
```

but this code copies all the files from `new folder1` to `new folder3`. How to do it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$folder1 = 'C:\new folder1'
$folder2 = 'C:\new folder2'
$folder3 = 'C:\new folder3'

Get-ChildItem $folder1 | Where-Object {
    Test-Path (Join-Path $folder2 $_.Name)
} | ForEach-Object {
    Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $folder3
}
```

It gets all the files that are in folder1, checks if they're also in folder2, and copies each one to folder3. Same thing as a one-liner:

```
gci 'C:\new folder1' | ? { Test-Path (Join-Path 'C:\new folder2' $_.Name) } | % { cp $_.FullName 'C:\new folder3' }
```

Comment: ok.. Will try this ! Thanks for your help ! its appreciated ! :)

Comment: It worked !! :) :) :)  Thanks a tonne !! its works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You are close to the answer. `Compare-object` should work.
Use it like so:

```
cd C:\folder1

$folder1 = Get-ChildItem -Path c:\folder1 -Filter *.txt  -File -Name
$folder2 = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\folder2 -Filter *.txt  -File -Name

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $folder1 -DifferenceObject $folder2 -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent  -PassThru | 
Copy-Item -Destination 'C:\temp\folder3'
```

`$folder1` and `$folder2` will contain only text file names.
Notice the use of `-passthru` with `compare-object` . The files coming out of the pipeline are copied to folder3

Comment: ok.. Will try this ! Thanks for your help ! its appreciated ! :)